# How can I use Java console app and Hibernate using Tomcat Context?

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, datasource, context.xml

I have some Java-console-apps. which are using Hibernate to take care some database stuff (I use MySQL). Now, I want Hibernate to use datasource from Tomcat Context. Could anyone tell me how?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch01.html#d0e404 here is an article for Hibernate telling you how to do this

Comment: Thanks Sean,I'm reading this article

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat wiki contains the needed configuration.

in context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/DVDStore">
  <Resource auth="Container"
  driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" maxActive="30" maxIdle="10" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/sakila" password="*****"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/sakila" username="*****"/>
</Context>
```

In WEB-INF/web.xml .

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>This is a MySQL database connection</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/sakila</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

In hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<!-- using container-managed JNDI -->
<propertyname="hibernate.connection.datasource">
   java:comp/env/jdbc/sakila
</property>
```

You can find more in [The TomcatHibernate Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/TomcatHibernate)

---

Edit:

In case you want to access the context directly, this is the way to do it problematically

```
    ServletContext sc = getServletContext();  
    String parameterValue = sc.getInitParameter("parameterName");
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I think this is configuration for web app. In my case, it is a java console app. I have read Tomcat wiki  and Tomcat document on Apache but I have no luck.

Comment: @hainp Why are you trying to store those application in tomcat? In any case you can extract the data directly from the file. If you have a web-app that takes its data from there, you can I. define a third place (a properties file for example) that they both will look at II. store the connection data twice

Comment: Each application is using c3p0 to take care database connection pooling. Now, I have about 5 apps that means approx. 25 connection-pools and I will have more apps which connect to 1 database server. So, I intend to use datasource from tomcat, that may help me to control number of connection pools even I have many more apps connecting to the database.
I know it's not the best solution but I haven't had any other idea.